# Matching rectifier with inverter

Tags: inverter, bridge-rectifier, matching

I'm trying to make a DIY wind turbine generator from a 3ph squirrel-cage induction motor but I'm having trouble matching the generator with the rectifier with the inverter. I'm not sure which parameters I must look for when matching. Also, I was wondering if this connection would work

[image: approximate scheme for self excitation for the induction motor]

P.S.: I attached an approximate scheme for self excitation for the induction motor

Comment: Looks like asynchronous induction motors. Those won’t work as a generator. What you want is a permanent magnet motor/generator.

Comment: It can be operated as a generator once it reaches a higher rpm than the synchronous speed with a 50 HZ frequency and a 4 pole generator 1500 rpm synchronous speed this would prove to work

Comment: Which you will generate and inject how?

Comment: Are you asking how i well generate the required speed if so the location where i intend to install the system has rated wind speeds of about 30 rpm with a gear ratio of 1:100 i would get around the required rotational speed

Comment: i am more concerned on how to match the parameters of my system correctly

Comment: Compared to what frequency you are going to inject, and how? Do yourself a favor, get an asynchronous induction machine and spin it up mechanically with nothing but a multimeter connected to it.  How much voltage does it give out? Load it electrically. How much voltage and current does it give out?

Comment: The question is too broad to answer in this forum. You need two inverters. You need a 3-phase, variable-frequency, regenerative inverter that can supply reactive VA for motor excitation while receiving power generated over the range of speeds defined by the characteristics of the  wind turbine and the range of wind speeds expected. If you want to produce single-phase AC power for use, you need a second inverter for that. The 3-phase inverter should probably have a 3-phase rectifier built into it.

Comment: Either as part of the three-phase inverter or as a separate power conversion stage, you need a buck-boost circuit that will receive DC from the three-phase inverter and provide regulated DC to the single-phase inverter. You may also need a "dump" circuit to dissipate braking energy in situations where the system cannot be controlled.

Comment: Before being concerned about matching parameters, you need to be concerned about understanding the basic system operation.

Comment: I plan n adding a capacitor unit  at the output terminals of the induction generator; it will supply the reactive power needed to generate a voltage at the output terminals of the induction generator.  
This would generate a residual flux or magnetic field in the stator coil at the induction generator. The voltage generation process will not occur if there is no residual flux. To get maximum power output from the generator the capacitance value must change appropriately, and for that, Induction Generator Control (IGC) is needed.

Comment: Plus power conversion in this system would go as follows                                                              AC from gen--> AC/DC --> DC/AC where the output AC frequency would match that of the grid

Comment: Please draw a schematic of what you are proposing.

Comment: I attached the picture to the question

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work.

The inverter is not designed to generate the excitation required to use an induction motor as a generator and the proposed design doesn't appear to have any other way to do so. End of story.

Comment: I appreciate the downvote. Bad news is not welcome. However, until the problems in the proposed scheme are addressed (yes, excitation is not the only one, an efficient 1:100 step-UP gearbox is ... problematic) it's the answer to the "also" part of the question.

Comment: This "answer" should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Though it is a concrete answer to the "also" part of the question, without which the rest is academic. Conversely, I think your comments are suitable for an actual (and better) answer.

Comment: As i previously stated, I plan on adding a capacitor unit at the output terminals of the induction generator; it will supply the reactive power needed to generate a voltage at the output terminals of the induction generator. This would generate a residual flux or magnetic field in the stator coil at the induction generator. The voltage generation process will not occur if there is no residual flux. To get maximum power output from the generator the capacitance value must change appropriately, and for that, Induction Generator Control (IGC) is needed

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer to the "also" part of my question why do you believe a 1:100 gearbox to be problematic

Comment: Efficiency losses. But I'll give you one hint : where high step-up ratio gearing is common, it's done with cycloidal tooth forms - or even lantern pinions, to avoid the friction arising from the pressure angles in involute teeth. You'll find these in clocks. But note this results in weaker roots. If I **had** to step up 100:1 I'd consider an involute stage followed by cycloids. But practically I wouldn't. For the few kW you're looking at, I'd use axial field ironless PM, and direct drive, both for efficiency and reliability. I recommend Hugh Piggott's designs; well proven in NW Scotland.

Comment: I am aware that using a direct drive PM configuration would prove to be more efficient but I am controlled with budget. Most of the parts I'm using for this project are used and fished from the scrap yard